# how can I input a list of lists to make a matrix and change columns by using map function

Tags: python, map-function

I can't get input a list of lists. I get this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8c5f7927bb96> in <module>
      9         print(liste)
     10 
---> 11 list(map(change, liste ))
     12 
     13 

<ipython-input-4-8c5f7927bb96> in change(liste)
      5 def change(liste):
      6         temp = liste[0]
----> 7         liste[0] = liste[-1]
      8         liste[-1] = temp
      9         print(liste)

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I tried making the list of lists manually
I wrote this-> liste = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
and it worked but I need to get this as an input.
Here's my Python code:

```
liste = input(" mat= ")

def change(liste):
        temp = liste[0]  
        liste[0] = liste[-1]
        liste[-1] = temp
        print(liste)

list(map(change, liste ))
```

Comment: Without a sample input and desired output, it's hard to give an answer without knowing what to do.

Comment: you can do: `import ast; list(map(change, ast.literal_eval(liste )))  `

Answer (score 1):

Use `

```
import ast
liste = ast.literal_eval(input(" mat= "))`
```

As your error notifies you of, `liste` is a `str`. Every `input` is in fact a string. By using `ast.literal_eval`, it evaluates it and becomes a list of lists.

Comment: Then someone inputs `import os; os.remove(...)` and you won't be happy. Better to use `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads`.

Comment: You are of course very right. If you write it as an answer, I'll remove mine. It all depends on who your users are, which I don't know in this case